# Java - Error Message: 'Cannot Convert from void to String

Tags: java, string, void

I am creating a simple console applet for an assignment and I have ran into an error when trying to run my app. The error is:
    'Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to String'.

The error occurs four times as I have a recurring 'ElseIf' statement.
Here is the element where the problem is:

```
String thirdNum = println("Would you like a third number?(Y/N)");
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import acm.program.*;

    public class abacusConsole extends ConsoleProgram {
        public void run() {
            println("This program is a basic calculator two numbers!");
            println("Operations that the program recognises: \n Add \n Subtract \n Multiply \n Divide");
            String operator = readLine("Which operator would you like to use?");

            if (operator.equals("Add")) {
                int n1 = readInt("First Number");
                int n2 = readInt("Second Number");
                String thirdNum = println("Would you like a third number?(Y/N)");
                if (thirdNum.equals("Y")) {
                    int n3 = readInt("Third Number:");
                    int total = n1 + n2 + n3;
                    println(+n1+" + "+n2+" + "+n3+" = "+total+".");
                } else if (thirdNum.equals("N")) {
                    int total = n1 + n2;
                    println(+n1+" + "+n2+" = "+total+".");
                } else {
                    println("Please reload the application and type in either 'Y' or 'N'");
                }
            } else if (operator.equals("Subtract")) {
                int n1 = readInt("First Number");
                int n2 = readInt("Second Number");
                String thirdNum = println("Would you like a third number?(Y/N)");
                if (thirdNum.equals("Y")) {
                    int n3 = readInt("Third Number:");
                    int total = n1 - n2 - n3;
                    println(+n1+" - "+n2+" - "+n3+" = "+total+".");
                } else if (thirdNum.equals("N")) {
                    int total = n1 + n2;
                    println(+n1+" - "+n2+" = "+total+".");
                } else {
                    println("Please reload the application and type in either 'Y' or 'N'");
                }
            } else if (operator.equals("Multiply")) {
                int n1 = readInt("First Number");
                int n2 = readInt("Second Number");
                String thirdNum = println("Would you like a third number?(Y/N)");
                if (thirdNum.equals("Y")) {
                    int n3 = readInt("Third Number:");
                    int total = n1 * n2 * n3;
                    println(+n1+" x "+n2+" x "+n3+" = "+total+".");
                } else if (thirdNum.equals("N")) {
                    int total = n1 * n2;
                    println(+n1+" x "+n2+" = "+total+".");
                } else {
                    println("Please reload the application and type in either 'Y' or 'N'");
                }
            } else if (operator.equals("Divide")) {
                    int n1 = readInt("First Number");
                    int n2 = readInt("Second Number");
                    String thirdNum = println("Would you like a third number?(Y/N)");
                    if (thirdNum.equals("Y")) {
                        int n3 = readInt("Third Number:");
                        int total = n1 / n2 / n3;
                        println(+n1+" / "+n2+" / "+n3+" = "+total+".");
                    } else if (thirdNum.equals("N")) {
                        int total = n1 / n2;
                        println(+n1+" / "+n2+" = "+total+".");
                    } else {
                        println("Please reload the application and type in either 'Y' or 'N'");
                    }
            }   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking at this line of your code

```
String operator = readLine("Which operator would you like to use?");`
```

and comparing it with the one which causes the error

```
String thirdNum = println("Would you like a third number?(Y/N)");
```

It looks like you misplaced `readLine` with `println`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your println function is declared as void (please post it's signature btw), but you are trying to assing it's result (void) to a String variable.

Comment: I think you mean "assign", not "assing".

Comment: +1 to Code-Apprentice for not half-assing.

Answer (score 1):

`println()` method has no return type, so it returns `void` and you cannot assign it to a `String` reference obviously.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String thirdNum = println("Would you like a third number?(Y/N)");
```

println or (printline) does exactly that. It prints a line and returns nothing. You try to put that nothing (void) into a string. That does not work.

You probably meant to use another

```
   readline
```